# SOAP - failed to load external entity

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I have a wsdl file that is automatically generated by the nusoap. The server side code is

```
    require_once('lib/nusoap.php'); //include required class for build nusoap web service server
    require_once('conf.php');
  // Create server object
   $server = new soap_server();
   // configure  WSDL
   $server->configureWSDL('Upload Files');//, $namespace);

   // Register the method to expose
    $server->register('upload_files',                                 // method
        array('files' => 'xsd:string'),                                    // input parameters
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'),                             // output parameters
        '',                                           // namespace
        '',                               // soapaction
        '',                                                      // style
        '',                                                  // use
        'Uploads files to the server'                                // documentation
    );

    // Define the method as a PHP function

    function upload_files($files) {
       //code here
    }

    // Use the request to (try to) invoke the service
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

WSDL seems to be generated properly and is located here: http://dannyphantom.zg5.ru/server.php?wsdl

The client side code fails almost immediatly, right when I try to create a SoapClient:

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');


$wsdl="http://dannyphantom.zg5.ru/server.php?wsdl";  // SOAP Server
   try {
        $client=new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>true, "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));   // Connect the SOAP server
        //code
    } catch(SoapFault $e) {
        //...
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //...
    }
```

Now, no matter what I try to do - every time I get an error:

> "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://dannyphantom.zg5.ru/server.php?wsdl' : failed to load external
>   entity "http://dannyphantom.zg5.ru/server.php?wsdl"

I feel like I've searched to whole Google and tried numerous fixes - nothing works. The url_allow_fopen is set to 1. I can open the link as a file manually. I have tried setting

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
```

before creating the new instance. cURL and openSSL extensions are loaded (even though they are not required for HTTP connection). None of this helped. I am totally out of any ideas. Would appreciate any help.

PHP version is 5.2. 
Client code is run from Drupal 5 (Don't think that makes any difference)